# Pandas str split a column and add it to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

so I have a dataframe with this information and for the release date, I want to str,split so that it only display the year.

how can i str.split the release date so that it only shows the year and label it "release year"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnUKM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['release year'] = df['releaseDate'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[-1])
```

Comment: thank you, how can i replace the current column with this one or add it to the beginin?

Comment: df['releaseDate'] = df['releaseDate'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[-1])

Comment: and how can I group those like years?

Comment: df.groupby(['releaseDate'])

Comment: If it solves the problem, don't forget to accept the answer, so that it won't keep popping up :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `year` and `month` attributes directly using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"data" : ["11-Jan-2020", "05-Feb-2020", "01-Mar-2020"]})
df["data"]=pd.to_datetime(df["data"], dayfirst=True)
df['year'] = df['data'].dt.year
df.head()
```

Your `df` will now look like:

```
        data    year
0   2020-01-11  2020
1   2020-02-05  2020
2   2020-03-01  2020
```